# How to structure repo for Netlify subdomain support?

Tags: netlify

Netlify subdomains work based on branches on a repo. If I have a domain say `xyz.com` and repo `Repo-A`, the master branch will deploy to `xyz.com` and `dashboard` branch will deploy to `dashboard.xyz.com`. However the dashboard and master branch are very different expect for a few visual elements.

I’m trying to figure out a clean way to structure the repo

```
Repo - A
(master branch)
   src/app
   package.json
   webpack.config.js


Repo - A
(dashboard branch)
   src/app
   package.json
   webpack.config.js
```

The problem with this approach is I’d have to change my webpack, package and src files extensively. 
I believe switching back and forth between branches will generate a lot of junk in the `dist/` folder too.

What’s the best repo structure to make this work? Are there tools to make life simpler for this use case?

Another approach -

```
Create a Release Repo that has release branches like master and dashboard.

master commits to Repo A which pushes build to master branch of Release repo
master commits to Repo B which pushes build to dashboard branch of Release repo
```

Is this a cleaner approach compared to first one? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature seems to be more for staging/development/production(master) when you are using them to track changes for review and doing pull requests to each sub-domain branch through the workflow. I don't use this feature, because it is easy to track workflow by creating [branch deploys](https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains/#branch-subdomains) anyway. Where I think this would really come in handy is when tracking versions of my site at subdomains for different versions.

When using a sub-domain for a totally different project, you should consider moving them to their own repositories and managing the project as it's own site at the sub-domain. Then entering a `CNAME` sub-domain entry into DNS to point to the `my-dashboard-site-name.netlify.com`
[image]

#### Mono-repo

You could have them in the same mono-repo if you don't want to make them their own repo, you would still separate the sites deploy. This is a little bit more complex than their own repository, but tools like `Lerna` are there if you want to maintain it that way. It does make for a nice way to maintain projects that re-use the same libraries that are not published to a package manager, but in the same mono-repo.